# How to send mail in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I tried to send a mail in oracle apex but I am not able to send because of this error

```
ora-24247: network access denied by access control list (acl)
```

in mail queue.

The error is due to smtp server settings in "manage instance" I guess

Comment: ACL are not configured to your schema llok at http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2010/03/17/oracle-11g-access-control-list-and-ora-24247/ to overcome this.

Comment: the blog url which u posted is not working..could u please explain me in brief

Comment: refer blog http://oraclehack.blogspot.in/2010/10/ora-24247-network-access-denied-by.html for step by step configuration. instead of UTL_MAIL use package APEX_MAIL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure ACL for your database by executing the following (system permissions would be required)

```
begin
    DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(
        acl => '/sys/acls/apex_mail.xml',
        description => 'Network permissions for APEX to send emails',
        principal => 'APEX_050100',
        is_grant => true,
        privilege => 'connect');

    DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(
        acl => '/sys/acls/apex_mail.xml',
        host => 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX');
end;
```

Update it with the actual IP address or host name of your SMTP server. 
If you are using APEX version different of 5.1.x please use the APEX schema name for the principal param (instead of APEX_050100)